# Test condition in if command

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Any idea why `echo` statement is being executed in both scenarios?

Outputs `it worked`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

rizwan=''
if [ -n $rizwan ]; then
  echo "it worked"
fi
```

Replace `-n` with `-z`, and it outputs `it worked` when expecting no output:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

rizwan=''
if [ -z $rizwan ]; then
  echo "it worked"
fi
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ tells you what is wrong with your script. Get into to the habit of using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may know it or not, but let's make it clear: `[` is not a part of the `if` syntax. I mean `if [ …` behaves like `if true`, `if false` or `if any_command`, where `[`, `true`, `false` and `any_command` are commands. They return exit status and this is what matters to `if`.

Even if `[` is a builtin (and it is in Bash), it behaves like a regular command. There's even a standalone `[` executable (e.g. `/usr/bin/[`) because it's required by POSIX.

This means `[ -n whatever ]` is just a `[` command with few arguments. Yes, `]` is just an argument, it's not a delimiter or anything like that. The command named `[` just requires `]` to be its last argument. This way the code is more legible, `]` serves no other purpose.

The command `test` is equivalent to `[`. The only difference is `test` does not require `]`.
`[ -n whatever ]` is equivalent to `test -n whatever`.

If the shell expands `$rizwan` to an empty string, the snippets `[ -n $rizwan ]` and `[ -z $rizwan ]` become `[ -n ]` and `[ -z ]` respectively. The `[` command is not aware there was something between `-n` (or `-z`) and `]` in your code, it gets exactly two arguments. Both tests are treated as the `[ STRING ]` syntax where `STRING` is either `-n` or `-z`. This syntax tests if `STRING` is not empty. Your tests always succeed because neither `-n` nor `-z` is an empty string.

To make the snippets work as `[ -n STRING ]` or `[ -z STRING ]`, you need to double-quote the variable. The shell, after expanding `[ -z "$rizwan" ]`, will pass exactly *three* arguments to `[`. They will be `-z`, the expanded value of the variable (even if it's an empty string) and `]`. The tool will get all the arguments you wanted it to get.

If unquoted `$rizwan` in your examples expanded to more than one word, `[` would get more than three arguments. In general the final result would depend on the variable content and the implementation of `[`.

Compare [**Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).

Note `[[` in Bash is different. It's a keyword, it's integrated with the shell parser, it changes some rules, it's actually aware of variables and quotes between `[[` and `]]`. If you used `[[` instead of `[` (and consequently `]]` instead of `]`), then your code would work as you expected. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32227/108618).

`[` is the portable one.

Answer (score 4):

As variable `rizwan` is empty, your `if` command becomes:

```
if [ -n  ]
```

The syntax `[ STRING ]` tests if the string is empty (no characters).
So in your case of `[ -n  ]`, the string `-n` is evidently not-empty.

Comment: As per my understanding  if [ -n $variable ] means to check if length of the variable is greater than zero . if yes than execute THEN section of script otherwise do not execute THEN section . how to overcome this.

Comment: `[` is a synonym for the `test` command but requires a final argument of `]`. This command has a lot of options and `[ STRING ]` is only one of them. See the [test man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html).