# shell: test with double bracket [[ does test on file, whereas single [ does not

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Having this simple line:

```
user@Host:~$ ls -> fileA fileB
user@Host:~$ [[ -d $dir_name ]] && rm * # $dir_name does not exist, empty variable
user@Host:~$ ls -> fileA fileB  #does not delete anything, as expected

user@Host:~$ [ -d $dir_name ] && rm *
user@Host:~$ ls ->  #empty, although there is a test, all files are deleted, why?
```

I know double bracket `[[` is an extension of bash (or introduced by ksh), but why does not standard test turn off, when the obvious exit status is 0 in example above?

Comment: This is a classic example of `Always-Quote-Your-Variable`

Comment: and why you should Always-Use `[[` in bash instead of the good ol `[` to avoid surprises

Comment: Ok, I understand the reason of quotes, but does it mean that `[[` does it for you? Or why did `[[` succeeded in my example? It did it for me?

Comment: You already have an answer below.

Comment: @Jetchisel Or "you should always use `[` to make your code portable". Whatever. The superior rule is "you should know the tools you use".

Comment: This is tagged as bash, I see no reason to use `[`

Comment: I do, it is one character shorter.

Comment: And an unexpected removal of files ....

Comment: [My answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1533643/432690).

Comment: Well, now I know. However, tell me some reasons why I should use `[[` instead of `[`, It seems almost the same, no more advantage over single `[` (only few)

Comment: @Herdsman, the `[` can't do `=~` and `>` comparison, the latter will have the same unexpected (if not fatal) results. The `[` is there for POSIX compatibility and historical raisins...

Comment: @Jetchisel I said, it does have FEW advantages, but in generel, it is the same.

Comment: The `[[` was added in `bashv2` so unless I'm using `bashv1+` I'd avoid using the `[` also `@(foo|bar|baz|...)` can be done inside `[[`, but at the end of the day it is still your script....

Comment: @Herdsman "In general, it is the same" leads to bugs.

Comment: @Jetchisel: Fortunately, bash 2.0 was released in 1996, so by now all distributions (including CentOS) should have it available.

Comment: @user1686 amen to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage would be `[ -d "$dir_name" ]`.

Normally, unquoted variables are subject to word-splitting: if `$dir_name` contains spaces it will expand to *multiple* arguments in the resulting command's argv[] array; and if it's an empty string it will produce no args at all. The same rules apply to `[`, which is nothing more than a built-in command (and indeed a standalone executable as well).

So your second command is not the same as `[ -d "" ]` – it actually expands to `[ -d ]`. Due to different arg count, it becomes a completely different expression – the `-d` no longer indicates a "directory exists" test, but instead is *itself* used as a string parameter for the "string argument is non-empty" test (like `[ foo ]`), which of course succeeds.

However, these rules *do not* apply to `[[`, which receives special treatment from the shell's parser. Variable expansion inside `[[` works differently – in many cases the argument is implicitly "double-quoted", so `[[ -d $foo ]]` and `[[ -d "$foo" ]]` are equivalent. That's where the difference comes from.

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary